# Views differ in storyboard and Simulator in iphone Pluses and X

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, storyboard

I've searched a lot for this and 99% of the problems are solved because there is an error or conflict in constraints(which is not my case). So, my top view is having a big white space when ran in the simulator on iPhone Pluses screen or iPhone X. The same thing on my own device(7Plus). So, this is how it looks:

[image: Difference between simulator and storyboard]

Comment: I noticed you have "Preserve superview margins" disabled, could that be it?

Comment: Are you linking your constraints to the safe area or to the view itself? This could be the problem

Comment: @breno silva disable the adjust scrollview insets in stortyboard from property inspector of viewcontroller.

Comment: @ekscrypto unfortunally no :(
They are linked to the safe area(top, trailing, leading) and to tableView(bottom)

Answer (score 0):

[image: Disable Adjust scrollview insets from storyboard]

Disable Adjust scrollview insets from storyboard

Hope, It's help to you.

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED IT :)

Something else was actually bothering me and when i solved it, everything ended up being solved.

So i had the home screen(with navigationController embeded in) which could link me to the login screen.

After logged in, this would link me(through storyboard references) to Menu storyboard(which is a tabbarcontroller connected to three nav controllers and their root VCs(through storyboard references)). On any of these VCs, i couldn't edit the navigation controller, adding item or bar button(that was my other problem).

I've deleted the first nav controller(on my home screen, that was not sooo much necessary) and now it all works fine, the views are ok in the simulator and xcode and i can edit the nav controllers.

Thank you guys anyway, hope this helps anyone else :)

Answer (score 0):

Try linking your constraints to the upper view instead of Safe Area.
Also, try adding this code to the viewController that is responsible for your tableView delegate methods:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return CGFloat.leastNonzeroMagnitude
}
```